# What proportion of natural numbers are of the form $(n^2-1)/24$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, asymptotics

### Motivation:

I found the following theorem online recently.

> **Theorem:** For any prime $p\ge 5$, we have $$24\mid p^2-1.$$

*Proof:* Let $p\ge 5$ be prime and $P=p^2-1$. Observe that $P=(p-1)(p+1)$. Since $p$ is odd, both $p-1$ and $p+1$ are even, and one is a multiple of four; hence $8\mid P$. Also, $p>3$, so $3\nmid p$, and exactly one of any three consecutive integers is a multiple of three. Considering $p-1, p, p+1$, then, we must have $3\mid P$. Hence $3\times 8=24\mid P$. $\square$

I showed this to a friend and she half-joked that this would make primes easier to find; just look for numbers of the form $(n^2-1)/24$ for natural $n$ to narrow things down. I remarked that that was kind of like saying, okay, each prime greater than two is odd, so that makes primes easier to find.

But it got me thinking . . .

### The Question:

> What proportion of natural numbers are of the form $$m=\frac{n^2-1}{24}$$ for $n\in\Bbb N$?

### Context:

It's been a while since I studied analytic number theory, so I don't have very sophisticated thoughts on the matter.

One way to approach this, I suppose, is to study the asymptotics of $(n^2-1)/24$ as $n\to \infty$. So I guess we could look at $O(n^2)$ as $n\to \infty$. [Since $0\%$ of natural numbers are perfect squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2055507/104041), it seems that $0\%$ of natural numbers are of the form $(n^2-1)/24$.

*Why am I not convinced by this heuristic?*

Well, like I said, my analytic number theory is rusty. Is "percentage" even an accurate way of describing the proportion?

*Edit:* I guess what I'm looking for is the [natural density](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) of such numbers.

Please help :)

Comment: 25, 49 and 121 are not of the form 24(n^2-1).

Comment: What's your point, @gnasher729?

Comment: Wouldn't the natural density of these numbers being zero prove the natural density of primes is zero? If so, [this seems like a much simpler proof than what is known!](https://mathoverflow.net/q/381456/42153)

Comment: $24|m^2-1$ for all $m$ not divisible by $2$ or $3$, not just for prime $m$

Comment: I know, @J.W.Tanner. How is it relevant though?

Comment: Generally, you search primes in a specific range. For example, all primes $p$ with 200 digits. so you should search for density of perfect squares in a specific range.

Comment: Natural density of these numbers would be zero as the asymptotic will be proportional to $\frac{n}{\sqrt{ \ln n}}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: I invite you to elaborate on that in an answer, @MokutekiJ; I'm likely to accept it!

Comment: Have a look at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4449391/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-de-natural-density-of-numbers-of-the-form-ax2-by2

$24(n^2-1)$ is of the form $ax^2 + by^2$ with $a=24$, $b=24$, $x = n$ and $y=1$

Comment: To fully understand, maybe take a look at Gauss compositions and natural densities of binary quadratic forms

Comment: This might also be interesting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4320361/density-of-integers-represented-by-a-binary-quadratic-form-is-zero/4320845#4320845

Comment: This goes more into depth of the constant of proportionality for the asymptotic: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.08307.pdf

I hope that helps ;)

Comment: Again, this is best handled in answer, @MokutekiJ!

Comment: Please explain why you think that integers of the  form $24(n^2-1)$ are related to the first Theorem (possibly there is a misunderstanding).

Comment: I told you my number theory was rusty! I mean $$\frac{n^2-1}{24},$$ of course! Never mind: I got an answer now. Thank you for asking for clarification, @BillDubuque.

Comment: You shouldn't accept an answer to a question that was not the one you meant.  This will end up confusing many readers.

Comment: Okay, @BillDubuque. I have edited the question yet again. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5):

The natural density is zero, as you say. But the algebra is not at all complicated: if we set a limit $N$, then the number of terms $\le N$ is exactly the integral part of
$$\sqrt{\dfrac{N}{24}+1}$$
So the density on $[1,N]$ is about $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{24N}}$. Which tends to zero.

Comment: But this clearly is not the question the OP meant  - see my comment on the question (and the edit to the question).

Comment: Hopefully, this is a quick fix for TonyK, @BillDubuque. I don't see anything wrong with an edit to this answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I answered the question as it was posted. I'm not going to go chasing after it as it changes, especially for such a trivial change.

Comment: It won't change again, @TonyK.

Comment: It is not respectful to the community to leave wrong answers with no warning. Why not simply make the easy update?

Comment: @BillDubuque: You have my permission to do it yourself, if you're so bothered by it. Not respectful? Oh for heaven's sake.